# What am I doing wrong with this simple click function?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make simple jQuery script. I have two divs. First is called 'but' and second is called 'tun'. What I want to do is when you click but -> tun hides and but has new class active. When you click on active tun shows and class active is removed. So it's kinda like toggle but I really don't want to use toggle becouse I need different actions on first and second click.

Here is my code:

```
$('.but').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.tun').hide('slow');
});
$('.active').click(function(){
    $('.tun').show('slow');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});]
```

Why it is not working ?

http://jsfiddle.net/wcwny064/

Comment: Because even though the element has the class `active` on it, you still also trigger your first function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.click()` function directly attach to `document`'s click event with a selector like this;

```
$(document).on('click', '.but', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.visible').hide('slow');
}).on('click', '.active', function(){
    $('.visible').show('slow');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

This way you delegate the event to document. At a `t` moment when click event occurs if document has element which matchs your selector, your function will run.

In your code, when you use `.active` selector and bind `click` event, there is no element with `active` class. Therefor you can't bind second `click` event.

Comment: Did you get the reason why your code didn't work? I tried to explain. BTW if any of the answers help you solve your problem don't forget to upvote it/accept it.

Comment: Yes now I know what was wrong. Accepted and upvoted :)

Comment: Be sure to check @a-wolff's answer too. Like he said in the comments, you may shorten your code. In this solution when the `.but` element has `.active` class and `click` event occurs, actually two functions will run. But because of the second one binds later you achieve what you want. It doesn't mean it's the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding event to specific elements, there is no on-the-fly processing regarding selector later. You can just delegate event. That's said, you could use following logic instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.active, .but', function(){
    $('.visible').stop().toggle('slow'); // stop() to handle multiple clicks
    $(this).toggleClass('active but');
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Yep, it's much shorter this way but OP want's two different functions for a reason. ;)

Comment: @EmreErkan You are correct, i missed this part of question: `but I really don't want to use toggle becouse I need different actions on first and second click`. But maybe the different actions could be DRYed too, depending what OP is expecting

Comment: I wanted to use it with animate.css so you can use different animations on first and on second click http://jsfiddle.net/wcwny064/6/

Comment: @WojciechZieliński What you could do is use following logic (check HTML markup): http://jsfiddle.net/wcwny064/8/  That's said, use the logic you find the most readable, your code has nothing wrong and exposes more easily the logic behind it

Comment: Oh thats clever solution !

Answer (score 1):

or you can do it like this

```
$('.but').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("active"))
    {   
      $('.visible').show('slow');
      $(this).removeClass('active');        
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.visible').hide('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: this is also brilliant ! :)